# How to check the inequality of all integers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to check if all 23 numbers in my array (the numbers are randomly generated) are NOT equal to each other but I can't figure out how to do it without a super ridiculous if statement.  Is there any other way I could do it?  Another option would be to check if any two numbers in the array are equal but the reason I posed the question the way I did was because I figured checking the equality of each pair would be harder than checking the inequality of all the numbers.

Comment: Hi Patrick, what have you tried? Mess your hands, write some code and show it to us!

Comment: Consider looking into for-loops.

Comment: @moonwave99 Hey sorry for the late reply, I kind of forgot I had linked my facebook to stack overflow and ended up using a different account for a while and just ended up logging into this one again for the first time in a while.  On the bright side, 3 years have passed, and I'm currently in my second year in college as a software engineering major! Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with two nested for-loops

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++)
    {
        int val = array[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] == val)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The first loop loops over every element in the array, while the second one checks if any of the values before the index of the outer loop are equal to the value at `array[i]`. You can safely use `j < i` for performance and to ensure that it doesn't return true on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm like the following to test whether every array element is unique:

```
boolean everyNumberIsUnique(int[] numbers) {
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      if(numbers[i] == numbers[j]) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

It simply compares each number against each other and returns `false` if any two numbers are equal.

Comment: This won't work, it will compare `array[1]` with itself and return false right away.

Comment: @Clashsoft Thanks for the hint, classic mistake. Forgot to add +i.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively low upper bound on your numbers (say less than 1 million) and don't really care about memory usage, you can just create a boolean array and set each element to true if its index is in your array. This is O(n), so its probably the best you can do, but, admittedly, you have to meet the above criteria.

```
public boolean allDifferent(int[] numbers)
{
    //everything in the array defaults to false
    boolean[] array = new boolean[upperBound+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[numbers[i]])   //if we've already seen this number (aka duplicate)
        {
            return false;
        }

        array[numbers[i]] = true;   //note that we have now seen this number
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: A boolean array might not be the best solution since each element consumes an entire byte. A `java.util.BitSet` might be a faster alternative that doesn't have the drawbacks of a generic `Set`.

Comment: @Clashsoft I had no idea `BitSet` was a thing. But I did warn that although it has linear time complexity, this solution does use a bunch of memory.